# What is the best way to communicate between Python softwares running on the same computer?

Tags: python, pipe

I used MailSlots with Delphi for my softwares when I needed dialogs between them (on MS Windows on the same coputer).
Now I need to do the same things but with Python and on MS Windows but also on Linux.
So : what is the best way to communicate between Python written software running on the same computer ?
For some firewall problemes I would prefer to avoid IP dialogs.
As I tested it, I don't want all the DIsk File share solutions.

So in brief :

> - 2 Python software on the same computer need to dialog.
> - No IP
> - No Disk File share.

Comment: You're looking for IPC, start [here](http://docs.python.org/library/ipc.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module has [Listeners and Clients](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection): "It basically gives a high level message oriented API for dealing with sockets or Windows named pipes."

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you could use [DBus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus), which has bindings for Python, and actually allows communication between processes even in different languages.

Unfortunately this would not be portable. I don't know what would be suitable on a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

How about one of them being a thread started by the another one?

Comment: Only if you're careful - don't forget the dreaded GIL. multiprocessing is far better for this - even Guido says so.